# Clebsch-Gordan coefficients and the decomposition of the tensor product of two irreducible representations of $SO(3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, quantum-mechanics

We will use $D^l$ for irreducible representations and $V_l$ for the corresponding vector space.

Given two irreducible representations of $SO(3)$, $D^{l_1}$ and $D^{l_2}$ ($l_1$ and $l_2$ are the same as $j_1$ and $j_2$ in Clebsch-Gordan coefficients). Their tensor product $D^{l_1} \otimes D^{l_2}$ may be a reducible representation of $SO(3)$. Indeed, we have
$$D^{l_1} \otimes D^{l_2} = \bigoplus_{| l_1 - l_2 | \leq l \leq l_1 + l_2} D^l$$

The identity is basically representing the same vector space in two different ways. The left hand side corresponds with the natural choice of basis of $V_{l_1} \otimes V_{l_2}$ induced by that of $V_{l_1}$ and $V_{l_2}$. The right hand side is a direct sum of subspaces $V_l$ of $V_{l_1} \otimes V_{l_2}$, each is invariant under $(D^{l_1} \otimes D^{l_2})(g)$ for any $g \in SO(3)$.

Clebsch-Gordan coefficients are basically a change of basis in the sense that they form a transition matrix that changes from the natural basis of $V_{l_1} \otimes V_{l_2}$ to the basis of $V_l$'s.

Now we still need to choose a basis for each $V_l$. My question is: what basis is chosen for each $V_l$ in the context of Clebsch-Gordan coefficients and why are they chosen this way or are they considered natural?

Comment: For the double cover $SU_2$, this is explained in sections 7.1 to 7.4 of the article http://www.numdam.org/item/10.5802/aif.2474.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix basic Lie group notation: $D^l= \exp (i\theta ~\hat {\mathbf n}\cdot {\mathbf L})$ is a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_operator_(quantum_mechanics)), where the three matrix generators **L** obey the Lie algebra *so(3)*; and, ipso facto, commute with the [quadratic Casimir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_element#Quadratic_Casimir_element) invariant $\mathbf {L\cdot L}$, whose eigenvalues are ***all*** $l(l+1)$ for integer or half-integer $l$, dubbed "***spin***", for an irreducible representation. (This invariant is proportional to the identity matrix for an irrep.)

- They therefore *completely* characterize  an irreducible  representation, the essence of your question: the Casimir is effectively an identity matrix times the above eigenvalue, acting on such.  The dimension of the irreducible representation indexed by $l$ is $2l+1$.

Your basic matrix reduction
$$D^{l_1} \otimes D^{l_2} = \bigoplus_{| l_1 - l_2 | \leq l \leq l_1 + l_2} D^l$$
consists of $(2l_1+1)(2l_2+1)$-by-$(2l_1+1)(2l_2+1)$ matrices on the left-hand-side  acting on the uncoupled basis for the vector space $V_{l_1} \otimes V_{l_2}$ of dimensionality $(2l_1+1)(2l_2+1)$.

The right-hand-side acts on the reduced vector space $\bigoplus_{| l_1 - l_2 | \leq l \leq l_1 + l_2} V_l$ of the same dimensionality, where each $D^l$ acts nontrivially *only* on the subspace $V_l$, of dimensionality $2l+1$, with ***null action*** on all other subspaces. The quadratic Casimir invariant ${\mathbf L}\cdot {\mathbf L}$ has eigenvalue $l(l+1)$ on each different subspace $V_l$, where $l$ varies between the limits indicated in the range of the direct sum.

So, this spherical basis is chosen by the quadratic Casimir invariant, and is considered natural, since it represents disjoint action of the above "huge" representation matrix you wrote: the right-hand-side huge matrix is a sparse collection of smaller block matrices on the diagonal, each of size $2l+1$-by-$2l+1$, for each of the $l$'s specified by the limits given. It represents overall rotation properties of the coupled composite system involved, in which you are presumably interested. You are interested in the properties of the box, not its contents.

The Clebsch-Gordan orthogonal matrix converts the l.h.s. to the r.h.s. basis outlined, where action of the *L*s is [straightforward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients#Spherical_basis_for_angular_momentum_eigenstates) for routine computations.

You may [illustrate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/632993/66086) this for $l_1=l_2=1/2$, composition of two doublets, to yield a singlet, $l=0$,  directly summed with a triplet, $l=1$.

SU(2) [double covers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charts_on_SO(3)) SO(3), but they share the *same* lie algebras,
*su(2)*=*so(3)*, so all your physics applications would be identical; further discussion of topology would disorient you rather than help you; recall your states are labelled by their Lie algebra eigenvalues *l*. It is vastly more important to actually learn how to deal with the concrete matrices as exemplified in the suggested illustration above! These are everyday-life issues.

---

**Response to comment hint request**:

Typically, you want to find the coproduct generators of your spin-1 $\otimes$ spin-1 generators,
$$J_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 0  \\
 1 & 0 & 1  \\
 0 &  1 & 0  
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$J_2=\frac{i}{\sqrt 2}\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & -1 & 0  \\
 1 & 0 & -1  \\
 0 &  1 & 0  
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$J_3= \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 &  0 & -1  
\end{array}
\right),$$
with Casimir   ${\mathbf J}\cdot {\mathbf J}=2 1\!\!1$.

That is, calculate the 9×9 matrices
$$
\Delta (J_i)= J_i\otimes {\mathbb I} + {\mathbb I} \otimes   J_i\otimes ,
$$
which [evidently satisfy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_representations#Lie_algebra_representations) the same *su(2)* Lie algebra--note how they relate to the direct product of group matches you inefficiency focussed on, first.

So, how do you reduce these to
$$
J_i \oplus S_i \oplus 0,  
$$
where the *S*s are the spin 2 generators
$$S_1=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} & 0 & \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$S_2=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & -i & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 i & 0 & -i \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & i \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} & 0 & -i \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & i \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} & 0 & -i \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & i & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$S_3=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -2 \\
\end{array}
\right) ~~~~ $$
(with Casimir $  =6~~1\!\!1$)  ?

Note the Casimir of the $\Delta(J_i)$s is not diagonal. So you must find the (sparse) Clebsch transition matrix *Q* such that the quadratic Casimir of the $Q\Delta(J_i) Q^{-1}$s *is* block diagonal, by contrast; with three  diagonal blocks of size
5×5, 3×3, and 1×1, i.e. the identity matrices in 5d , 3d, and 1d, multiplied by 6, 2, and 0, respectively. (e.g., the 9,9 diagonal is 0.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What is the quadratic Casimir invariant? My guess is that it is the matrix of $D^{l_1}(g) \otimes D^{l2}(g)$ for some $g \in SO(3)$? And what you said described its eigen-structure. You mentioned spherical basis, and this basically answered my question about over which basis are Clebsch-Gordan coefficients defined. What I'm still not convinced is that the spherical basis feels more natural than other possible basis for each subspace. Maybe it's just a convention?

Comment: You *need* to review addition of angular momenta, as in, e.g., Sakurai & Napolitano, Ch 3.82. The spherical ("coupled") basis is superior for computations, as it does not  bother with the components of the coupled system, but examines the overall rotation features of it! I will add a preamble paragraph reviewing the underlying Lie algebra structure which I wrongly assumed you appreciated...

Comment: Thanks! I'll read Sakurai for more details.

Comment: By the way, can you give me some hints regarding the transition matrix: I formed the 9-by-9 Clebsch-Grodan matrix $Q$ for $j1=j2=1$. $R$ is a randomly generated 3-by-3 rotation matrix (so it's in $SO(3)$). $Q$ was not able to transform $R \otimes R$ into a block-diagonal matrix with 1x1, 3x3, 5x5 blocks. Then I tried the 3-by-3 Wigner-D matrix $W$, and $Q$ did block-diagonolize $W \otimes W$. Can I say Clebsch-Gordan is not chosen for the canonical basis of $SO(3)$, but is chosen for Wigner-D matrices, which I believe is a representations of $SO(3)$ over the complex vector space?

Comment: So you could not find the transition matrix with [these](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevC.72.055203) entries to reduce the coproduction of generators? One *always* works with generators, not their exponentials!! I could probably work it out, but in a different question, not a footnote... [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/473712/representation-of-so3-acting-on-3-index-tensors-in-zees-group-theory-book).

Comment: Apologies, the first link above is wrong (buffer remnant...). I meant [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Clebsch–Gordan_coefficients#_j1_=_1,_j2_=_1).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll read your answer in the other question first and will let you know if a new question is submitted. The information you have provided so far is very helpful!